# Clip large Raster Geotiff File in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I have a 250m resolution raster file which is needed to be clipped using a mask layer. I am trying to do it with gdalwarp through Clipper tool in QGIS but it is taking forever. I tried using R (mask function) but that too didn't help.
Are there any methods to do it with less computational burden on the system?
This is the code I was using `gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -q -cutline "D:/Mesh/MRB/ncrb trial 2.shp" -tr 0.002083333 0.002083333 -of XYZ "D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif" D:/Mesh/MRB/result.tif`.
This is the datafile: ftp://164.132.26.83/data/recent/BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif (approx 7.5 GB).
This is the gdal info data about the file:
`Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif
D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif.aux.xml
Size is 172800, 67200
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,83.999167206000010)
Pixel Size = (0.002083333000001,-0.002083333000001)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
ATTRIBUTE_LABEL=BDTICM_M
ATTRIBUTE_MEASUREMENT_RESOLUTION=1
ATTRIBUTE_TITLE=Absolute depth to bedrock (in cm)
ATTRIBUTE_UNITS_OF_MEASURE=cm
CITATION_ADDRESS=shanggv@bnu.edu.cn / tom.hengl@isric.org
CITATION_ORIGINATOR=College of Global Change and Earth System Science, Beijing Normal University / ISRIC - World Soil Information
CITATION_URL=http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/2016MS000686
CONFIDENCE_INTERVAL=M
DATA_FORMAT=Byte
DEPTH=None
DOWNLOAD_FTP_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif
HORIZON_LOWER_DEPTH=5000.00 m
HORIZON_UPPER_DEPTH=0.00 m
KEYWORD1=bedrock
KEYWORD2=depth
NO_DATA=255
PROJECT_URL=http://soilgrids.org
PUBLICATION_DATE=2017-03-10
RANGE_DOMAIN_MAXIMUM=5000
RANGE_DOMAIN_MINIMUM=0
SERIES_NAME=SoilGrids250m
SLD_NAME=soilgrids250m:BDTICM
SLD_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/legends/BDTICM.sld
TECHNICAL_SPECIFICATIONS_URL=https://github.com/ISRICWorldSoil/SoilGrids250m
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left (-180.0000000, 83.9991672) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Left (-180.0000000, -56.0008104) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9999424, 83.9991672) (179d59'59.79"E, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9999424, -56.0008104) (179d59'59.79"E, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Center ( -0.0000288, 13.9991784) ( 0d 0' 0.10"W, 13d59'57.04"N)
Band 1 Block=172800x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-32768
Overviews: 86400x33600, 43200x16800, 21600x8400, 10800x4200, 5400x2100, 2700x1050, 1350x525`

Comment: How did you try to do that? Add also gdalinfo report about your source image. It may be suboptimal for clipping.

Comment: @user30184 this is the code gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -q -cutline "D:/Mesh/MRB/ncrb trial 2.shp" -tr 0.002083333 0.002083333 -of Gtiff "D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif" D:/Mesh/MRB/result.tif

Comment: Your source file is organized as rows `Block=172800x1`.  Clipping would need less resources with tiled image. Make a tiled copy as `gdal_translate -of GTiff -co tiled=yes BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif tiled_BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif`and have a new try.

Comment: @user30184 I did build tiled copy of the file but the data seems to have changed.. and there are a lot of differences between original and tiled data

Comment: It should not change any pixel value. How did you notice the differences?

Comment: @user30184 right clicked at any point using "identify features" pointer and checked both the values

Comment: Your original image has overviews which are downsampled versions with bigger pixel size. It may be that "identify features" tool is taking the pixel value from some overview instead of the full resolution. I would rather test with gdallocationinfo http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html by giving explicit x and y pixel values.