# Converting part of raster into .xyz file

Tags: qgis, raster, convert, xyz

I have a very large raster whose GDAL Info is as below:

```
Size is 172800, 67200
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
DATUM["WGS_1984",
SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,83.999167206000010)
Pixel Size = (0.002083333000001,-0.002083333000001)
Metadata:
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
ATTRIBUTE_LABEL=BDTICM_M
ATTRIBUTE_MEASUREMENT_RESOLUTION=1
ATTRIBUTE_TITLE=Absolute depth to bedrock (in cm)
ATTRIBUTE_UNITS_OF_MEASURE=cm
CITATION_ADDRESS=shanggv@bnu.edu.cn / tom.hengl@isric.org
CITATION_ORIGINATOR=College of Global Change and Earth System Science, Beijing Normal University / ISRIC - World Soil Information
CITATION_URL=http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/2016MS000686
CONFIDENCE_INTERVAL=M
DATA_FORMAT=Byte
DEPTH=None
DOWNLOAD_FTP_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/data/recent/BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif
HORIZON_LOWER_DEPTH=5000.00 m
HORIZON_UPPER_DEPTH=0.00 m
KEYWORD1=bedrock
KEYWORD2=depth
NO_DATA=255
PROJECT_URL=http://soilgrids.org
PUBLICATION_DATE=2017-03-10
RANGE_DOMAIN_MAXIMUM=5000
RANGE_DOMAIN_MINIMUM=0
SERIES_NAME=SoilGrids250m
SLD_NAME=soilgrids250m:BDTICM
SLD_URL=ftp://ftp.soilgrids.org/legends/BDTICM.sld
TECHNICAL_SPECIFICATIONS_URL=https://github.com/ISRICWorldSoil/SoilGrids250m
Image Structure Metadata:
COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left (-180.0000000, 83.9991672) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Left (-180.0000000, -56.0008104) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9999424, 83.9991672) (179d59'59.79"E, 83d59'57.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9999424, -56.0008104) (179d59'59.79"E, 56d 0' 2.92"S)
Center ( -0.0000288, 13.9991784) ( 0d 0' 0.10"W, 13d59'57.04"N)
Band 1 Block=172800x1 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Gray
NoData Value=-32768
Overviews: 86400x33600, 43200x16800, 21600x8400, 10800x4200, 5400x2100, 2700x1050, 1350x525`
I want to extract from it a part of data as xyz file. But I cannot seem to know how to do it. I have tried `gdal_translate -of XYZ -a_ullr -89.2972 60.0378 -117.719 44.901 "D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif" "D:/Mesh/MRB/ascii shangguan for NCRB 0125 .xyz"
```

but it writes an xyz file more than 100GB and the size is increasing even more than 100GB as I write the question. Can I just have the data for "-89.2972 60.0378 to -117.719 44.901"?

Comment: You have asked about the same question with a bit other words https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245261/clip-large-raster-geotiff-file-in-qgis?noredirect=1#comment385318_245261. I consider this is a duplicate.

Comment: @user30184 that question is if i can convert it to clip the same raster.. not for extracting xyz file..i need to do both actually

Comment: Your original is compressed tiff tile `COMPRESSION=DEFLATE` and it holds 32 bit data `Type=Int32`. Such data as an uncompressed plain text format like XYZ takes evidently much more space. Your gdal_translate command does not make sense  at all. Read http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html `-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry:
    Assign/override the georeferenced bounds of the output file`. What you need is -projwin which is documented on the same page. And think again what is upper left and what is lower right before giving values for -projwin.

Comment: Did you already try `gdal_translate -of XYZ -projwin -117.719 60.0378 -89.2972 44.901 "D:\\Mesh\\Shangguan et al. (2016) Bedrock data\\BDTICM_M_250m_ll.tif" "D:/Mesh/MRB/ascii shangguan for NCRB 0125 .xyz"`? For comparison try also with GeoTIFF output. The output size should be so small that compression or tiling are not important. Remember from your other question that reading a block from a tiff file that is written row by row is inefficient and tiled tiff would be faster and take much less memory.

Comment: @user30184 I tried gdal translate with projwin and it works! Though the file size is 4 gb but it gives the result. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XYZ is a verbose, uncompressed ascii format so you should anticipate large files.  However, you have quoted your area as `-a_ullr -89.2972 60.0378 -117.719 44.901`.  I'd have expected GDAL to give you an error message for those numbers since -117 is further west than -89 meaning you've actually quoted URLL and not ULLR.  Perhaps because you are in WGS84, GDAL is content to go 'the long way round' the globe.  I notice your prime meridian is Greenwich so perhaps you meant: `-projwin -117.719 60.0378 -89.2972 44.901`.  This will give you an area of 26.52 x 15.13 degrees (instead of about 333.48 X 15.13! which would indeed be a massive file in xyz).  Use -projwin to clip a subwindow.  The -a_ullr parameter assigns new dimensions to your output but does not clip (so you may still expect a large file if you use that instead of projwin).  For more information see the documentation [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html).

Even the area you intend in XYZ is going to be a big file especially with 15 decimal places for your X and Y values and int32 for your z values (though I'd not expect quite as much as 100GB+).  Do you really need to use XYZ?

Comment: I need to find a way to get pixel values with their lat and long in a sheet so that I can process it with R or excel

Comment: You can use XYZ, but just watch how you define the area as per the first paragraph in my reply.

Comment: Could you edit your answer a bit because -a_ullr just writes new metadata while -projwin is used for clipping?

Comment: You are absolutely right, of course, and I should have read my reply back before pressing submit.  Thank you for mentioning it.